# How come I am being detected behind VPN?

Tags: vpn

I have been using a few cheaper VPN services trying to hide my original location. But some internet services have been able to detect me and block me from accessing them.

How could they detect me behind VPN? I thought this was not possible.

Do I have to search for VPNs with a specific set of security features or all would be traceable as well?

**EDIT**

How did I set up VPN? I got username and password, created a new network in win7 and connected to it via wifi (**not direct dial!**). Somehow, I was detected by specific services and my account was deleted within 1 day.

Comment: What VPN service are using currently? How did you set it up? Can you add more details to the question? Specifically exactly how you setup your VPN. A VPN can leak your IP if you don't set it up properly.

Comment: Also please go to https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ while your VPN is active and provide us with the results (run the extended test).

Comment: Also are you sure they're blocking **you** and not the VPN? Are you certain it's IP-based?

Comment: @Thebluefish The account I created was deleted. So they somehow notices that "someone" is using VPN. Are you saying that the VPN I was using is blacklisted? If yes, where can I find secret VPN? Top VPN companies with paid VPN service told me that all their server are in public domain.

Comment: If the place you're going to happens to be fairly popular, free/cheap VPNs can possibly be used before. I haven't used a VPN in a couple years, but I know that many public VPNs I used from flat-rate monthly services were already blacklisted or used so it took a great deal of time trying to find one that worked for my purposes. Remember that many forums and blogs have plugins that will alert the admins anytime multiple accounts are signed up with the same IP, too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are facing such issues because of using Shared Dynamic IP. Which may used by someone else at times and being noticed and checked by the website to see if the request is coming from an IP that is a known proxy.
Most cheap VPN vendors, share their VPN servers among many users. If  one, or several, other users who also use that VPN connection have suspicious network activity through the VPN (e.g. they may have a virus or malware trying to spam through mail servers, etc.), the website will label all traffic coming from that VPN server's IP address as suspicious.

In order to overcome this problem, I recommend getting a **dedicated IP** for your VPN connection which can only be used by you and is not shared.
Here is a short article that explains dedicated IP in nutshell:
http://www.purevpn.com/blog/dedicated-ip-vpn/

Hope it could help